# What does Renown do?

Tags: magic-the-gathering-puzzle-quest

In the mobile game, Magic the Gathering: Puzzle Quest, cards can have Renown.  What does the Renown keyword mean for MTG: Puzzle Quest?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While many keywords have different meanings from the original card game, it looks like Renown acts the same, as evidenced from [this post](https://www.facebook.com/MagicPuzzleQuest/posts/676627529119133) and [this site](http://decktester.com/Cards/Glossary).

From the official site, [Renown](http://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/feature/magic-origins-mechanics-article-2015-06-22) does the following:

> Renown triggers the first time a creature with renown deals combat damage to a player. The ability puts some number of +1/+1 counters on that creature (the number after the renown keyword). Also, it causes the creature to become renowned. So, if your [Rhox Maulers](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=398663) deals combat damage to your opponent (and trample may help there), it will beef up to a mighty 6/6. Now that it's renowned, its renown ability will no longer trigger, but it will get a better effect from Enshrouding Mist.

Since a Planeswalker counts as a player, damage to a Planeswalker will *also* activate the Renown keyword.

Comment: In general, the rules in MtG Puzzle quest are very different than in the CCG.  (Vigilance and Defender are very different for instance).  so, why do you think Renown is the same?

Comment: @John, okay, I did some more research and it looks like Renown is the same in Puzzle Quest as it is in the card game. Let me know if this is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

I found a [glossary](http://decktester.com/Cards/Glossary) for the terms in the game, and for renown it states:

> The first time this creature deals damage to a Planeswalker, gain +X/+X where x is equal to its Renown value

I also found a [discussion](https://d3go.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=31&t=36459) between players that seems to confirm this:

> Renown adds +x/+x to a creature when it deals damage to the enemy opponent.

Comment: That glossary is sweet....  So hard to find via google however....  Thanks!

Comment: @John I included a link to that glossary in my answer as well; it's the second link.